# Linq: Xml to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> deferred execution?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, .net-3.5, deferred-execution

I'm trying to pull out the `Roles` below into an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`

```
<PROJECT PROJECT_NO="161917"> 
  <CONTACT CLIENT_ID="030423253272735482765C" CONTACT_NO="1"> 
    <ROLE ROLE_ID="2" ROLE_DESC="ARCHITECT" /> 
    <ROLE ROLE_ID="5" ROLE_DESC="INTEGRATOR" /> 
  </CONTACT>
</PROJECT>



private static ProjectContact BuildProjectContactFromXml(XElement xml)
    {
        ProjectContact projectContact = new ProjectContact();
        projectContact.ProjectId = SafeConvert.ToInt32(xml.Attribute("PROJECT_NO").Value);
        projectContact.Roles = xml.Elements()
                                    .First()
                                    .Elements()
                                    .Select(role => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
                                                            SafeConvert.ToInt32(role.Attribute("ROLE_ID").Value), 
                                                            role.Attribute("ROLE_DESC").Value));

        return projectContact;
    }
```

My question is about deferred execution of this Linq statement.  It is my understanding that when I return this ProjectContact, the Linq statement has not yet executed.  Is there a way to force the execution of this statement so that it happens in this method, rather than when someone tries to access the Roles?  I think I could force the execution of the statement by calling .Count() on it, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't finished with the question and it posted!  I'll finish writing my question, one minute :)

Comment: Roles is a IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,string>>, sorry about that.

Comment: In .NET 4 they now have tuples so we don't have to do lists of keyvaluepairs anymore for these things.
new Tuple<int,string>(int value1, string value2)

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa, cool, didn't know about that, but I'm currently working in a 3.5 project.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa: I believe the syntax is actually `Tuple.Create(int value1, string value2)`  (types inferred from paramters without being specified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`projectContact.Roles` is going to be a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` is that what you want, or do you want it as a List or DIctionary? For a List, just tack `.ToList()` at the end of the statement.

For a Dictionary, it's a bit trickier:

```
   projectContact.Roles = xml.Elements() 
                                .First() 
                                .Elements()
                                .ToDictionary(
                 role=> SafeConvert.ToInt32(role.Attribute("ROLE_ID").Value),
                 role=> role.Attribute("ROLE_DESC").Value));
```

UPDATE:  In you comments you state that Roles id `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`.  Technically, that could be either a Dictionary or a List, although in the former case, you really can't use it's Dictionary-ness via that interface. For that matter, you can use much of it's List-ness in the latter case -- but it seems you specifically don't want that ability.

So, tack on `.ToList();`.  It will be a List behind the scenes, but without going to extradinary lengths, users will still only be able to use it as an IEnumerable.

Comment: On the ProjectContact, I do want the Roles to be an IEnumerable.  The reason being is that I don't want the user of the object to be able to edit the collection of Roles.  If I made it a List or a Dictionary, they would be able to Add() to it.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If the datatype of `.Roles` is array, you could simply append `.ToArray()` after your `.Select()`, and that would ensure that the query is executed.

Either way, you can execute a `ToList()` or `.ToArray()`, and you'll get execution of the query.